# Is it possible to forge AMF requests from outside a flex application?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4, amf, amfphp

We are having a problem at my company that has been troubling us for months and i just thought i'd throw this out here to get some help. Our system runs with Flex/AMFPHP and we normal get weird requests from unknown sources to delete huge chunks of valuable data on the server. We suspect it might be an attacker. So i am wondering if it is possible to forge AMF request in a DOS fashion. If this is possible, i'd like to know how and what to do to stop it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to create AMF requests and send them to your server. You do this with your Flex app, and someone else can do it too. This can be with malicious intent. Your server code should be hardened to handle these requests, as the axiom goes: Never trust your client. If you want some advice more specific to your system please get in touch. ( I run the Amfphp project)

Comment: Hi Ariel, thanks for the answer. I would definitely like to get in touch. We suspect it might be an outside attack. Do you think making some sort of request/response interceptor on the AMFService level(if possible) to log application level operations coming from the client would be a way to monitor things properly? I was looking at the AMFphplogger class [AMFphplogger](http://community.silexlabs.org/amfphp/reference/classes/AmfphpLogger.html) but i cant seem to find much documentation on how to use it. My email address is denachural@gmail.com. I'll appreciate some good tips. Cheers